# Why do standard libraries have better portability then system calls

Tags: system-calls, standard-library

I'm studying for my final in my Systems programming class, and my notes mention to use standard libraries where possible because they have better portability than system calls, but not WHY. Is this because that system calls vary between operating systems??

Not sure if it affects the answer, but the class uses C and it's run in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

System calls vary a lot between different OS, but be aware that standard librairies can vary too (e.g. different implementations on the same OS).

Answer (score 0):

system calls vary a lot between different OS but standard libraries expose the same API